# Run one file among multiple files in azure webjobs

Tags: python, azure, azure-webjobs

I am trying to run a contionus azure webjob for python.

i have 6 files where main.py is the main file, other files internally importing each other and finally everything is being called from main.py, now when i am trying to run only the first python file is getting executed, but i want that when the webjob will start only main.py will be executed not anything else. how to achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite simple. In azure webjob, if the file name starts with `run`, then this file has the highest priority to execute.

So the most easiest way is just renaming the `main.py` to `run.py`.

Or add an `run.py`, then call the `main.py` within it.